# Trying to send multiple items from a database using php to a Java Android App. It is not working. Why?

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-studio

Trying to select books from a database that have the same section (Fiction, History, Science) and get them into an array in java which I can use to populate a list view. My problem is that I cannot get my php/java to work. What is wrong with my code? I am currently trying to use the id numbers to extract them from the database but is there an easier way to use it by using just the string like "Fiction"? 
[Here is a link to a picture of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZFk.png).
[Here is a screenshot of my xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuSUi.png).

Here is my php code.

```
$response = array();
$titles = array();
$authors = array();
$ids = array();
$sections = array();

$idfirst = $_POST["id"];

$id = (int)$idfirst;

$id += 1;
$step = 0;

for($id; $id<=$id+=2; $id++){

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM booktest WHERE id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $book_id, $title, $author, $id, $section);

    $pass = false;

    $response["success"] = false;
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $titles[$step] = $title;
        $authors[$step] = $author;
        $ids[$step] = $id;
        $sections[$step] = $section;
        $pass = true;
    }

    $step += 1;

}

if($pass){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["titles"] = $titles;
    $responsee["authors"] = $authros;
    $response["ids"] = $ids;
    $response["sections"] = $sections;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Here is my main java code

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray();
String responseGetter[] = {"book_id", "title", "author", "id", "section"};

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    final Button bHomeHistory = findViewById(R.id.bHomeHistory);
    final Button bHomeFiction = findViewById(R.id.bHomeFiction);
    final Button bHomeScience = findViewById(R.id.bHomeScience);

    bHomeFiction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success){
                            JSONObject titles = new JSONObject((Map) jsonResponse.getJSONObject("titles"));
                            Iterator x = titles.keys();
                            JSONArray titlesJSONArray = new JSONArray();

                            while (x.hasNext()){
                                String key = (String) x.next();
                                titlesJSONArray.put(titles.get(key));
                            }
                            ArrayList<String> titlesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                            if (titlesJSONArray != null){
                                int len = titlesJSONArray.length();
                                for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
                                    titlesArray.add(titlesJSONArray.get(i).toString());
                                }
                            }
                            String set = titlesJSONArray.getString(1);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(set).setNegativeButton("YAY", null).create().show();
                        }else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Fetch Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            BookRequest bookRequest = new BookRequest("1000", responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(HomeActivity.this);
            queue.add(bookRequest);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the BookRequest Class

```
public class BookRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String BOOK_REQUEST_URL = "http://hhspatriots.000webhostapp.com/bookReceive.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public BookRequest(String id, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, BOOK_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", id);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is your PHP code outputting JSON correctly? or is the problem in the Android code?

Comment: One thing that is missing is you are not setting your response headers in your php code. You should have header('Content-Type: application/json'); before your final echo.